# Assetic resources are not loaded when using controller in dev environment

Tags: symfony-2.3, assetic

I have a strange problem wth Symfony 2.3 and Assetic.

When working with XAMPP I was developing a Symfony 2.3 site. All works well, however, I have moved the site to a RHEL5 machine. After that, the site does not load because assetic resources stay loading for ever.

For example, by using Firebug I saw this script trying to be loaded:

`http://server/app_dev.php/js/base_jquery.ui.widget_3.js`

Browser get stuck loading that resource. If I publish the asset to web directory, and not using controller, so, with this link `http://server/js/base_jquery.ui.widget_3.js`, it works.

Of course, I don't want to publish all the time when I make a change to some resource. For r two reasons: it delays long time to publish because there are a lot of assets, and the web/js directory get filled with several files.

I suspect this is a security issue, but I don't know where it is.

Can you point me to some direction please?

EDIT:

This is how I am referencing the assetic:

```
    {% javascripts filter='yui_js' output='js/base.js'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.js'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js'
            '@MutualContratosBundle/Resources/public/js/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

Thanks
Jaime